# Multiple files javascript - readonly variables (how to edit them)

Tags: javascript, scope, leaflet

My question is very basic but it makes me totally stuck.

I need to make some changes to an existing project. In this project we have a leaflet map with markers and a search bar, and when making a new search, I would like to edit the map's markers.

All these "components" are in different files:

index.js in the "main" export {mymap};

in home.js

```
var markers = new Array();
markers.push(putMarkers(blablabla));
export {markers, elt};
```

component2

```
import {mymap} from './index.js';
import {markers, elt} from './home.js';

// Here I would like to set mymap and markers, but they are read only
```

So for example here, I would like to set the map's markers but it is read only. How can i have variables that I can edit between files?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: dont import the markers from the other file and just create your own?

Comment: How are the variables read only? They should be changeable after the import.

Comment: Wolfgang Stengel  : Where trying layer = new Array();
index.js:formatted:24503 Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:/laragon/www/project/src/scripts/filterCountry.js: "layer" is read-only

Comment: Craicerjack  : I also need to remove the markers from the existing map